# replace strings in url using regular expression

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I am really poor in regular expressions, So that is the reason i am asking the basic question here. I want to change some strings with slashes in a url in javascript. Please help me to get out from this.

This is my url

```
http://mysite.local/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/56x/qewewq1312321dfde5fb8d27136e95/m/u/music6_1_1.jpg
```

And i want to replace 'thumbnail/56x' with 'image' like

```
http://mysite.local/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/qewewq1312321dfde5fb8d27136e95/m/u/music6_1_1.jpg
```

How can i get with regular expression?

Comment: Something like `url.replace("thumbnail/56x", "image");`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddewm14e/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thumbnail\/56x` regex would replace the exact `thumbnail/56x` part in your link with image.

```
> "http://mysite.local/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/56x/qewewq1312321dfde5fb8d27136e95/m/u/music6_1_1.jpg".replace(/thumbnail\/56x/g, "image")
'http://mysite.local/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/qewewq1312321dfde5fb8d27136e95/m/u/music6_1_1.jpg'
```

`thumbnail\/\d+x` regex would replace any number in the `thumbnail` part like `thumbnail/673px` with `image`.

```
> "http://mysite.local/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/56x/qewewq1312321dfde5fb8d27136e95/m/u/music6_1_1.jpg".replace(/thumbnail\/\d+x/g, "image")
'http://mysite.local/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/qewewq1312321dfde5fb8d27136e95/m/u/music6_1_1.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use Javascript string replace function.

Try following:

```
var str = "http://mysite.local/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/56x/qewewq1312321dfde5fb8d27136e95/m/u/music6_1_1.jpg";
var res = str.replace("thumbnail/56x", "image");
```